# Find solutions of $f(2020)x+f(2019)y=1$ where $f$ is Fibonacci sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations, fibonacci-numbers

I need to find at least one solution of
$$f(2020)x+f(2019)y=1$$ 
with $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, where $f(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, starting at $f(0)=0$, so that:
$$f(0)=0,\qquad f(1)=1,\qquad f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2).$$

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please notice that questions here are typically better received when they include some more context, such as what is the problem from, why is it important to you, or what have you tried. See also [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For every natural number $n$ you have
$$f(n+1)^2-f(n)f(n+2)=(-1)^n.$$

Comment: Yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities